# Python minimum required version code check tool

Tags: python, source-code, code-analysis, requirements-management

What do you suggest for checking Python code and know the minimum required Python version I need to run it?

Answer (score 1):

I know of [pyqver](https://github.com/ghewgill/pyqver) and used it sometimes but it seems it's been years with no developed/updates, so it could still be useful if you're dealing with old scripts but if you have to check code that requires one of the most recent Python ( > 3.3 ) version you can't rely on it... I don't know if there are newer tools for that purpose.